# Accept terms of use rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

What is the best way to add a check for accepting terms of use in a rails app?

I can't seem to get `validates_acceptance_of` working quite right. I added a bool to my user model (was that necessary?). And then have a checkbox that returns either true/false.

I feel like I'm just making a silly little mistake. Any ideas?

Comment: Some snippets would help on deciphering the solution!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your model,

```
validates_acceptance_of :terms
```

If you're using `attr_accessible` in your model then make sure you also add,

```
attr_accessible :terms
```

In your view,

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.check_box :terms %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

There is no need for an extra column in the users table unless you plan on denying access to users who have not accepted the terms of service, which won't exist since they can't complete registration in the first place.

Comment: It's worth noting that lawyers might mandate keeping a record that a user has accepted t+c's... I reckon best practise is to save a boolean value into the db.

Answer (score 19):

This is a working Rails 4 solution:

Terms of service doesn't need to be a column in the database

**Form**

```
= f.check_box :terms_of_service
```

**models/user.rb**

```
validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: true
```

And most important, devise will sanitize your parameters and terms of service will be removed from the submitted params. So:

**registrations_controller.rb**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
      u.permit(:full_name,
        :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :terms_of_service)
    end 
  end
end
```

Comment: If you're only going to need the validation when the user signs up you can add on: :create to the validator.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working solution for Rails-6.1 (I18n) + Devise-4.8.0 + SimpleForm.  No need to add a column in the "users" table in DB.

**View**

```rb
 <% label_str = t('read_html', mylink: link_to(t('terms'), '/a/b/c')) %>
 <%= f.input :terms_of_service, label: label_str, as: :boolean, checked: false %>
```

Or, if you use Indo-European languages only, you can make it a little more simple, like:
`label_str = (t('agree_html')+link_to(t('terms'), '/a/b/c')+'.').html_safe`

**/app/models/user.rb**

```rb
attr_accessor :terms_of_service
validates_acceptance_of :terms_of_service, on: :create
validates_presence_of   :terms_of_service, on: :create
```

**/app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```rb
Devise::ParameterSanitizer::DEFAULT_PERMITTED_ATTRIBUTES[:sign_up] << :terms_of_service
 # see /vendor/bundle/ruby/*/gems/devise-*/lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb
```

### Explanation

In the User model, `on: create` guarantees it is read **only** in creation. If you need to reevaluate the condition in updating, too, specify it accordingly, like `on: %i(create update)`.

In the User model, I add `validates_presence_of` to play safe. The reason is, `validates_acceptance_of` will not be executed when the parameter `terms_of_service` is nil, in which case `validates_presence_of` will catch it and set an error. Admittedly, if the data are always submitted via the web-interface you have built AND your implementation is working perfectly, the value should be always either true or false and never be nil. So, `validates_presence_of` should not be necessary in this sense. It does no harm, though (except you'd need to be a little careful in manual user creation, bypassing the web-interface, such as from the Console).

The last one is neccesary for use with *Devise* for the same reason as in the answer by @vladCovaliov; that is, to prevent *Devise* from sanitizing your custom parameter, which is not a column in the database table.  The one-liner in the example above can be stated in any files as long as you are sure it is read at the run-time and after Devise Ruby code. `application_controller.rb` is one of the sure places (though I guess there is a better-fitting place). Make sure the sentence is put **out of** the `class ApplicationController` block.