# Rails accepting terms before creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Let's say before a user is allowed to view the creation page of a Model, they are required to accept some terms.  The workflow would be like:

User clicks on "create MODEL" -> Brought to a terms page, must accept before moving on -> MODEL creation page

If a user copies the url to the creation page, they should be redirected to the terms page.

What's the best way of going about this?  I was thinking of using the `session` variable somehow...but I can't think of a clever enough idea.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the following routes:

```
get 'terms' => 'MODEL#terms'
get 'new' => 'MODEL#terms'
post 'new' => 'MODEL#new'
```

The "create MODEL" should send a GET request for /terms. Accepting the terms should POST to /new. If the user pasted /new in the URL, he'll be directed to terms instead.

Alternatively (or additionally), you can have the /terms POST a variable, `:terms_accepted => true` to the MODEL creation page, and on that page, check `if :terms_accepted == true`. If not, redirect to the terms page.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the acceptance of the terms to the model itself, then you don't need a construction with an extra page and redirect if someone enters in the wrong place. Instead the user can only submit the form for creation when he/she accepts the terms.

You can add the following to the model:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :terms_of_service, :acceptance => true
end
```

And then make sure you have the checkbox for this in the new %{model} form.

Also see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#acceptance and [Accept terms of use rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324048/accept-terms-of-use-rails)